# Tengo problemas para introducir imágenes en mi programa con Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Básicamente he estado utilizando diversas formas de resolver este problema y de usar el método PhotoImage, pero sin éxito.

```
import tkinter as tk


lg=tk.Tk()
lg.title('Bienvenido a la aplicación que muestra una imagen')
lg.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Axel_\Desktop\KzApp\Bit\kzbtmp.ico')

logimg=tk.PhotoImage(r'C:\Users\Axel_\Desktop\KzApp\kezellogog.gif')
lblimg=tk.Label(lg,image=logimg).place(x=100,y=100)

lg.mainloop()
```

El programa funciona, carga incluso la imagen que usé como ícono con el otro método, pero en el caso de la imagen GIF que utilicé, solo se abre la ventana con fondo gris, pero no muestra la imagen.

Tengo la última versión de Python.

Comment: algún error por consola?

Comment: Generalmente, cuando un widget no se carga, es por que surgió un error durante o antes de su creación. Cuando un error sucede, la ventana de tkinter NO se cierra automaticamente, se mantiene abierta, e incluso responderá a binds establecidos antes del error (esto sucede al menos si usas el idle de Python). En conclusión, revisa tu consola, y si hay algún error, podrías agregarlo a la pregunta porfa?

Comment: Prueba cambiando esta linea `logimg=tk.PhotoImage(r'C:\Users\Axel_\Desktop\KzApp\kezellogog.gif')` por esa linea `logimg=tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Axel_\Desktop\KzApp\kezellogog.gif')`